# Unsure about the tense of “My passport was stamped by a man”

Tags: parsing

I have an uncertainty with this sentence:

> My passport **was stamped** by a man etc.

Would "**Was stamped**" be a present perfect or a past simple tense? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My passport **was stamped by** a man

This is an example of the simple past **passive voice**. To change it into the active voice, the subject (a man) becomes the agent

> A man **stamped** my passport

This is a sentence in the **simple past**. In this context, to stamp something is to use a rubber stamp that can either have a specific date or words carved or molded on the underside. The small instrument is used for printing on documents

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply :-)